# Release history of the app in AppStore/iTunes Connect

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, app-store-connect

How I can see the **release dates** of the previous versions of my app in **AppStore/iTunes Connect**?

I had shipped several updates in the past and I would like to know when exactly I uploaded them etc. 
I checked everywhere and I cannot find any information about the release history of the app there.
Is it just me or AppStore Connect lacks such a basic feature?

Comment: It's available in iTunes. Just search for your app click on the `Show All Version` link.

Comment: Ok, it is in iTunes and not in iTunes Connect. Not exactly what I was looking for but it's definitely better than nothing. Thanks! Can please you post your comment as an answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It's available in iTunes. Just search for your app click on the `Show All Version` link.

Since the redesign of ItunesConnect this has moved to `Pricing and Availability`. Here you will find `Last-Compatible Version Settings` where you can selected the available versions.

Comment: i didn't find show all version link under Sales and Trends module. can you tell me with the detail ? I mean, where this option resided under sales and trends?

Comment: It was there before the iTunes Connect redesign. See my edit.

Answer (score 19):

1. Go to [Google](https://google.com/) and search for `"<app name> App Store"`
2. One of the first results should be the App Store page (on itunes.apple.com). Click it
3. Click "Version History" in the **What's New** section

   [image]
4. View detailed historic release notes, version numbers, upload dates

   [image]

Answer (score 8):

Follow the steps to track your all app version release to App Store.
1. **Login** using your developer account credential.

2. Choose **My Apps** from all available services.
3. From all available apps, **choose a particular app whose details you wants** to check.
4. **Choose Activity** from top menu bar.
5. From iOS History (at left side bar) **choose App Store Versions**
You will find list of release version for that app. **For release date click on detail disclosure button**.
[image]

Comment: Is there any option to export this as history file as like other metrics?

Comment: @wesley I don't think so. But why you do require this history?

Comment: @wesley yes you can get an export. I have followed the network comms and iTunes servers respond with proper json. For example this gives list of versions: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/<PUT_YOUR_APP_NUMERIC_ID_HERE>/buildHistory?platform=ios while this gives details for each version: https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa/ra/apps/<PUT_YOUR_APP_NUMERIC_ID_HERE>/trains/<PUT_YOUR_VERSION_ID_HERE>/buildHistory?platform=ios of course you need to be logged in, or do it from command line curl using saved cookies from a previous call

Comment: As of January 2023, this is now under the menu on the left side of the App Store section, General / Version History.

Answer (score 1):

[2021] If you open the App Store on the iOS device and navigate to your App, you will find the full version history with version and release notes under the Version History" tab.

Comment: It only shows releases in the past half-year. Not all of your releases are listed here.